# Can't send message to FB

Tags: facebook, ios7, xmppframework

FB authentication is proper and i can receive messages. Only issue is when sending messages to a FB friend. No error messages or warnings are being shown, but the message is simply not delivered to the FB friend.

This is the string that i am sending

```
<message xmlns="http://www.facebook.com/xmpp/messages" to="-FB_ID@chat.facebook.com">
<body>my_message</body></message>
```

Any one having same issue?.

Comment: No, its nothing, my mistake, I got a bit confused between notification and chat api. Are you using all the parameters in your request??

Comment: Yeah, cause It used to work perfect and I haven't made even a small change in that. Suddenly now it isn't working. There is no issue with updating presence and receiving messages. Issue only exists in sending..

Comment: Try this [previous questions][1] maybe can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813542/facebook-xmpp-chat-api-send-message-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed.

Author replied me:

```
OK, I haven't done anything with Facebook chat but why are you setting the xmlns?
```

That exactly was my problem. I was sending the xmpp messages as shown below:

```
<message xmlns="http://www.facebook.com/xmpp/messages" to="-FB_ID@chat.facebook.com">
<body>dd</body></message>
```

When I removed the xmlns attribute, everything is fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

The "from" parameter is missing in your requset. Message format should be like this:

```
 <message from="-sender_ID@chat.facebook.com" to="-receiver_ID@chat.facebook.com">
 <body>your_message</body>
 </message>
```

Comment: I did add that. That is not the issue. It used to be okay without it also. Now even with the from param isn't working.

Comment: @Deepukjayan did you try with different friend ids, i mean your code seems to be correct maybe it is not working with a particular id, due to some fb exception itself??

Answer (score 1):

Is this something to do with the 5000 friend limit ?  I mean, you are not allowed to have more than 5000 friends on FB, therefore, I'm guessing there is a security issue that stops you posting once you hit that limit ?

Comment: this isn't about posting. I am talking about xmpp chat in FB, nothing with posting in FB.